# What Are the Possible Ways That URL Can Be Redirected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, apache

I inherited a small web-project. It contains static HTML pages with some Javascript. One of these HTML pages contains a map with different areas of the map linked to various external pages. Here is an example of such a link. The custom fields are implemented using jQuery to make the map work:

```
   <area target="_blank" href="http://example.com" shape="poly" coords="212,367,226,373,227,373,226,379,224,380,224,383,227,383,227,384,229,391,230,391,230,395,231,395,231,396,239,396,239,397,243,398,235,429,249,432,241,468,206,460,210,444,211,444,211,440,212,440,212,437,213,437,213,434,214,434,214,430,215,430,215,426,216,426,218,416,219,416,219,415,222,415,222,416,225,415,223,400,219,399,218,394,219,394,219,390,218,390,218,388,217,388,216,385,210,381,212,380,211,378" />
```

Now, when this link is clicked, for 10 seconds there appears a redirect page which then redirects to `http://example.com`. The problem is that I cannot find where the re-direct occurs to eliminate it. I have scoured the Javascript and HTML files to no avail. I am suspecting that there may be some Apache re-directs setup.

The question is how else could this re-direct be implemented? Where else can I look?

Comment: In your code the href is the same as the webpage it redirects to (`http://example.com`). So are you saying that the page it redirects to is the same as the href? If so, then maybe javascript is intercepting the link click and showing some kind of overlay for 10 seconds. It might also be using a meta refresh tag (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/meta-refresh/)

Comment: To clarify, `http://example.com` is where I would like it to go. However, a different page appears for 10 seconds before the site goes to `http://example.com` I tried searching for address of that page in site's directory, thinking it would be hard-coded into a JS file. However, I had no luck with that.

Comment: Can you not just change the `href` attribute of the `<area href="xxx">` tag to go directly to the site that you want it to go to?

Comment: That is what I did. It still persists with the re-direct.